# How to populate two or more textboxes with combobox selection from MSA DB from different columns and rows

Tags: visual-studio-2013, combobox

I am working on a VB windows Form Application using Visual Studio 2013 project. I want to use a combobox to fill textbox in my form selected from my MS DB Access with different table.

I have a MS Access DB Named DataDB and i have a Form Named Form1 with a Combobox on it Named cboData and three textBox Named txtName, txtPhone and txtAddress. The DataDB hold my customer Name, Phone and Address.

I want to use the ComboBox to access the DataDB and use the value to populate three textBox Named txtName, txtPhone and txtAddress in the same form once the customer is selected in the form.

Comment: `I want  to...` is not a question and this post doesnt show any code for us to help with.  Also it cant be both VB6 and VB.NET, so first figure out what language you are using, then fix the tags.

Comment: i am using a Visual Studio 2013 with VB install on it to develop the program. I have done the design.

Comment: i am using a Visual Studio 2013 with VB install on it to develop the program. I have done the design. i Have develop the same program on MS Access and trying to translate it to VB windows Form Application. bellow is my code for the MS Access                                                    Private Sub cboItem1_Change()
txtName = Me.comboBox.column(3)
txtPhone = Me.comboBox.Column(4)
txtAddress = Me.comboboxx.Column(5)

End Sub

Comment: VB.NET is nothing like Access-VBA.  There are no columns in the WinForms NET combobox.  I think you have a fair amount of research ahead of you before you write any code

Comment: so from my question stated how will you do that in VB.Net?